# Writing a line from two sibling nodes in a TikZ tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, trees, tikz-trees

Recently I am struggling on TikZ and it is really difficult to find options and solutions considering it is such a huge and comprehensive library.

What I actually would like to do is drawing, in a tree, a line that connects two adjacent sibling nodes. That's all.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Just add a node name for each the nodes you want to connect and then use `\draw` to connect them.  E.g. `node (A) {XxX}` and `node (B) {YyY}` will create nodes (A) and (B). Then at the end of your tree add `\draw (A) -- (B);`

Comment: Gonna try this...

Comment: Post an answer man, you got this :) THANX a lot

Comment: Ah, sorry, how to make it dashed??

Comment: `\draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);`?

Comment: Just have a look at the [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). There is a chapter on Trees (18. Making Trees Grow). The second page of that chapter shows *exactly* what you want to do. It uses Alan's suggestion to do so (and Harish's to make it dashed).

Comment: @AlanMunn If you wish, can you please write a super minimal answer for this or maybe suggest a duplicate?

Comment: @percusse Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sufficient to label any nodes that you want to connect and then simply use regular `\draw` commands to connect them. This is independent of what method you use to draw the trees.  Below is a combined example using both regular TikZ tree methods or `tikz-qtree` methods (which provides a much less cumbersome syntax for most trees.  In practice you would probably use one or the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
% using regular TikZ tree methods
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {A}
    child {node (B) {B}
        child {node {D}}
        child {node {E}}}
    child {node (C) {C}};
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (C);


\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip

% using tikz-qtree
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=3em]
\Tree [.A
         [.\node (B){B}; 
        [.D ]
            [.E ]
         ]
         [.\node (C) {C}; ] 
      ]
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]